# can i user - in function as i want clean url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in Ci can i use "-" in function as i need clean url

for example

my URL is below:
  www.xyz.com//test/media_page?media_id=1&course_id=2

but i need below:

www.xyz.com/test/media-page?media-id=1&course-id=2

when i change the function is saying some errors so i am confirming this so if anyone   having the idea please share with me.

thanks in advance....

please tell me more things if for this i have to change any more things.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hyphens in function names in PHP. Only letters, numbers and underscores are acceptable.

`Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.`

From http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

If you want to achieve this you can use routes in Code Igniter. Alternatively, you can include and implement a `_remap` function in your controller to send URLs with hyphens to the corresponding function, replacing hyphens with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use _remap() method in codeigniter to implement this

**Example**

Use this method in your test controller. GET parameters you can receive using $this->input->get(). This won't make any trouble

```
public function _remap($object, $params)
{

  //replace your hyphen as underscore
  $method = str_replace('-','_', $object);

   //verify method is exist or not
  if(!method_exists($this, $method_name))
  {
    //throw error or load default method index

    die();
  }

  //trigger the method
  call_user_func_array(array($this, $method_name), $params);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to custom [CodeIgniter Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) to translate the `-` to `_`. Something along these lines:

`$route['test/media-page?media-id=:num&course-id=:num'] = "test/media_page?media_id=$1&course_id=$2";`